# Where are Google Chrome bookmarks stored in macOS for multiple profiles?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bookmarks

I can find bookmarks for one profile at `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks`. However I don't know where I can find the bookmarks for the other profile. Where should I look?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you've stated, the default location is found within:

`Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`

However, when you create additional profiles, the name Chrome uses on the associated profile folder is a generic numbered name (e.g. `Profile 2`, `Profile 3` and so on)

The best way to find the folder path for a particular user is to:

1. Within Chrome switch to the other profile
2. Chrome will open a new window using the profile you just selected
3. Now in the URL/address bar enter the following: `chrome://version`
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. The browser window will now provide a whole range of data
6. Look for the **Profile Path** entry
7. This will show you the exact file path location of the profile you selected at Step 1
8. Now you can use that path to find all the data associated with that profile

Comment: For me it was in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1`. If you go through the finder, make sure hidden files and folders are shown (using `Cmd+Shift+.`) because `Library` is hidden.

Answer (score 5):

Additional Chrome profiles are stored in:

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1`,
`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 2`, etc...

along with their corresponding bookmarks file.